# Is there any other strong SQL injection to secure the data?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I am submitting data in a database using PHP which is working but I want to set more secure my code so that I used SQL injection but one of my friend hacks my data within 10 min. Is there any other strong SQL injection to secure the data?

I tried

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $email=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
  $subject=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject']));
  $mobileno=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['contact']));
```

**SQL Query**

```
// prepare and bind
  $sql="INSERT INTO creatcontact (email, subject, mobileno) VALUES (?,?,?)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email, $subject, $mobileno);
  $stmt->execute();
//redirect code
 header('Location: index.php');
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
```

Comment: Use the PDO for connection to a mysql, PDO already has several treatments against SQL Injection

Comment: @rikardo_paiva. Object-Oriented is not a good idea?

Comment: You shouldn't be both escaping the variables and using parameterised queries, you only need one or the other. How you have it now, you're going to end up with mangled data in your database.

Comment: As to how your friend hacked your site, there's no clues in the small section of code you've written. If they're really your friend, maybe they'll help you understand how they did it and you can come back with a more specific question if you can't fix it between you. (Or maybe they're not really your friend after all.) Meanwhile, I'm voting to close this question as too broad, because I don't think it can be answered in its current form.

Comment: @rikardo_paiva mysqli is every bit as suitable for this job as PDO, there's really no reason to switch. @ Narendra: not sure why you think PDO wouldn't be OO though, the "O" actually stands for "Objects".

Comment: Oh, and also, "SQL injection" is the name of the attack, not the defense. You're probably not going to get hired if you go into an interview and proudly explain how you "added SQL injection" to something.

Comment: @IMSoP, Yes He hasn't provided me any clue that's why I upload question here. I thought may be I missed something in the code.

Comment: @IMSoP,  "SQL injection" is the name of the attack, not the defense.
 Then what is the way to defense?

Comment: In general, it's just "SQL injection prevention" or similar. The particular use of a query with placeholders that you then send values for later is called a "prepared query", or more specifically a "parameterized query".

Comment: I recommend getting better friends who help you learn rather than leaving you to beg strangers for help.

Answer (score 1):

Using bind variables,  as you have done, is the best defense against SQL injection. The other primary defense against SQL injection and  other  security vulnerabilities is validation.   Validation can to help protect against second-order SQL injection attacks, where the value inserted into the database is  incorrectly concatenated into a SQL statement. It can also help protect against the data being used in other injection attacks such as XSS.

Validation should ideally be checking for a known good values (white listing).    In your case, for example, you may want to ensure that the email, subject, and phone number are restricted to specific characters and numbers.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Egret, where the value inserted into the database is incorrectly concatenated into a SQL statement.?

Comment: My main point is that you want to validate as well as using the binding that you're currently doing.  I don't see any security issues - but @IMSoP is correct that you'll end up by putting escaped data in the database, which may cause functional issues.  Its hard to tell completely without more information about how this is used and what your fried did.